# Point Cloud Library Viewer Makes QT Creator GUI Application Crash

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am trying to build a sample application in QT Creator (version 5.2.1), with qmake, and PCL 1.7 on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine. The written code runs without problem, however when I am adding the following line of code, the application crashes unexpectedly.

```
 boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer(new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer("3D Viewer"));
```

I also have to mention the fact that the PCL code (without the QT Gui part) used in the above mentioned application, has been tested on a Windows 10 machine having PCL 1.8 installed, and it works perfectly. The build was done with CMake on Windows.

Does anyone know why is this vizualization problem appearing and how to get over it?

Comment: Make sure that you are using binaries that are compatible with your compiler. This is important in that mingw binaries and msvc binaries will be incompatible with each other.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Second, if the binaries would not be compatible, the code should not work up to the point where I introduce that line related to the viewer.

Comment: It was my first thought because you are allocating memory here.